# How to run long running report in the background

Tags: oracle10g, oas

Oracle Application server 10g

I need to run the long running reports in the background because while the report is running the cursor is loading and the control doesn't return to the user

this feature exist in oracle 6i by set the following parameter

RUN_PRODUCT( REPORTS, 'r_1', ASYNCHRONOUS, RUNTIME, FILESYSTEM, pl_id, NULL);

How can I accomplish the same in OAS 10g?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `RUN_REPORT_OBJECT`? If so, have you set `REPORT_COMM_MODE` to `ASYNCHRONOUS`?

Comment: I am very glad because Jeff is answering my question, yes I tested this parameter and it worked well, thanks

Comment: I need another thing if you'll not mind, I need to get the current running report status which exist in the Application Server admin console, such as "25 of 255 Pages completed", how can I get this value to display it to the user in oracle forms 10g

Comment: I'm not sure if that's even possible - but I recommend you ask that as another question.